# Código ajax não está funcionando

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Estou começando no ajax e tenho tido dificuldade para entender o erro que está dando nesse exemplo. Clico no botão e nenhuma ação é feita.

**HTML:**

```
   <html>

      <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <title></title>
      </head>

      <body>
         <input type="button" value="Testar" onclick="myAjax();"></input>
      </body>

   </html>

   <script>
       function myAjax() {
          $(document).ready(function()
          {
             $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'teste.php',
             data:{action:'call_this'},           
             success:function(html) {
                alert(html);
             }
          });
          return false;                
        }
      </script>
```

**teste.php:**

```
  <?php
     if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
        echo "YES";
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: Qual erro que ocorre? Aparece alguma mensagem?

Comment: Ele não diz nada, apenas não dá nenhuma resposta ao código @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teste assim

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Testar" id="myAjax"></input>
</body>
</html>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myAjax").click(function(){
    $.post( "test.php", { action: "call_this" })
    .done(function( data ) {
      alert( data );
    });
  });

 });
</script>
```

o seu teste.php continua igual

Comment: Funcionou cara... valeu

Answer (score 0):

Retire o `onclick="myAjax();"` do seu elemento `input`, e comece a declarar os eventos da seguinte forma:

Reescrevendo um pouquinho seu botão de ação:

```
<input type="button" id="um-teste" value="testar" />
```

Agora, alterando o `javascript`:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#um-teste").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'teste.php',
        data:{action:'call_this'},           
        success:function(html)
        {
            alert(html);
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

No trecho de código acima, na linha `3` que começa com `$("#um-teste")` você *ordenou* que o botão `input`, ao ser *clicado* disparará a função que está contida ali dentro. Logo, irá iniciar a execução do seu `ajax`, com isso você descarta o uso da função atribuída no próprio elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, cara faz assim, coloque o $(document).ready... no início do script, e dps crie a função somente com o ajax!

```
   <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#myAjax").click(function(){

    $.ajax(
      url: "test.php", 
      data: { action: "call_this" },
      .success(function( data ) {
      alert( data );
    });

  });

 });
</script>
```